# c# winform control sizing issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently creating a winform and i am witnessing some very odd behaviour?

Basically in designer when adding a text box everything looks great in terms of sizing:

[image]

However once i run the application the following sizing issue is seen:

[image]

As you can see the text becomes tiny and the textbox shrinks with it? has anyone else come across this oddity and have an idea on how best to resolve?

***EDIT***
Adding another image to show the issues which i still cannot fathom ie on testing multiple controls it appears to be related to the textbox and RichTextBox controls?

[image]

***EDIT Issue Identified***

I recreated a new winform application and tested post changes and found that the problem is related to adding the nuget package Fontawesome.sharp, as soon as a control from that package is added to the form then the input box-sizing all goes awry; at least i can use that to drill into it further now.

Comment: Let me guess you have 2 monitors and they don't have the same resolution

Comment: Check code and make sure the sizes are being change in the code.

Comment: Make your app DpiAware.

Comment: @Franck no not that as you can see above the group box has the same font size throughout but the text box on render using the same font settings as the group box is somehow looking very small indeed and i am only using 1 monitor

Comment: Did you try placing the control inside `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: @SH7 its literally a new form the groupbox label is set to fontsize 12 and so is the tb, however on render it appears to the eye that the tb is more like fontsize 6 where it should be the same size as the groupbox; very confused as to why